# How to write Russian characters in file?

Tags: python, windows, unicode, python-2.x, python-unicode

In console when I'm trying output Russian characters It gives me ???????????????

Who know why?

I tried write to file - in this case the same situation.

for example

```
f=open('tets.txt','w')
f.write('some russian text')
f.close
```

inside file is - ?????????????????????????/

or

```
p="some russian text"
print p
?????????????
```

In additional Notepad don't allow me to save file with Russian letters. I give this:

> This file contains characters in
>   Unicode format which will be lost if
>   you save this file as an ANSI encoded
>   text file. To keep the Unicode
>   information, click Cancel below and
>   then select one of the Unicode options
>   from the Encoding drop down list.
>   Continue?

How to adjust my system, so I will don't have this problems.

Comment: This question's title is rather poorly chosen!

Comment: Is it really `?` or rather `�`?

Comment: @Gumbo: the `?` is used when the target isn't able to *store* the given character because it's outside the charset range. E.g. databases and output (file/stdout/etc) writers. The `�` is used when the target is able to *display* the given character, but don't do because it's outside the range of the charset it is instructed to use. E.g. webbrowsers. All with all, it makes sense that `?` is been used here.

Comment: @Carl - and I was going to suggest that the poster just make them tragic with undercurrents of brooding and mysterious.

Comment: @BalusC: it should rather throw an exception.
@user375373: Notepad gives you the correct hints (both for using Notepad and for programming): choose a Unicode encoding such as UTF-16 (also called "Unicode" by Microsoft) or UTF-8.

Comment: @Philipp: I wholeheartedly agree that, but unfortunately the truth is different at many places in many languages. Those "unknown" characters will simply be trashed or replaced. The target doesn't know "better".

Comment: It seems that this user-somenumbers doesn't know how to accept answers or ignores it.

Comment: If one of these answers helped you solve your problem, please click on the check mark next to it so that the author gets proper credit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a worked-out example, please read the comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# The above encoding declaration is required and the file must be saved as UTF-8

from __future__ import with_statement   # Not required in Python 2.6 any more

import codecs

p = u"абвгдежзийкл"  # note the 'u' prefix

print p   # probably won't work on Windows due to a complex issue

with codecs.open("tets.txt", "w", "utf-16") as stream:   # or utf-8
    stream.write(p + u"\n")

# Now you should have a file called "tets.txt" that can be opened with Notepad or any other editor
```

Comment: I get the error: SyntaxError: non ASCI character '\xff' in file 'my python file', but no encoding declared

Comment: I did declare the encoding, that's what the second line is for. And there is no character '\xff' (which is `ÿ`) in the file. Are you sure that you did everything correctly, and do all characters show up correctly in Notepad?

Answer (score 11):

Try opening the file using codecs, you need to

```
import codecs
```

and then

```
writefile = codecs.open('write.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
```

Comment: When I use this this to write Russian characters to a file, it outputs gibberish

Answer (score 2):

You need to define file encoding if it contains non-ASCII chars.

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: It not help! And even when I'm truing save Russian text in Notepad it says me that i cant save. Because i lose my data.

Comment: Follow the advice given by Notepad and choose one of the Unicode encodings.

Comment: Please, just do not code in Notepad. It is really, REALLY bad idea. Try vim or emacs. If those two are too scary -- try Notepad++ or Scite or something more sane than Notepad.

Comment: @petraszd: We are only using Notepad here because of its Unicode support.

Answer (score 1):

What console are you using?  Chances are, your console doesn't support that language.  Make sure that your console supports Unicode (and that your app is sending Unicode strings).

**Update:**

To address the update to your question regarding problems with Windows' Notepad:  Click File->Save As, and then choose "Unicode" from the "Encoding" drop-down list.

Comment: Which consoles did you try?  What OS are you using? Can you successfully output Russian characters to your console using a programming language other than Python?

Comment: I did not notice when it happaned. But it happend, after i install same extension like PYMSSQL and ODBC. Can it be out of it?

Comment: If the behavior changed after installing an extension, un-install the extension and see if the old behavior returns.  It would not be unheard-of for an extension to introduce unexpected problems.

Comment: @user375373: it would be really helpful if you answered bta's question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you typing in console too or only seing the results in console? This looks a pep-0263 problem as petraszd said.

```
print p.decode('your-system-encoding')
```

should work in console (I don't know what is the encoding system you use for Russian)

If you are using a .py file, you need to place `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` (replacing utf-8 with Rusian encoding) on the top of the file and I think there is no need for the `.decode` in `print` if your OS is configured with the right encoding. (at least I don't need it but I don't know how it works with Russian)

Comment: When i'm typin all is ok.
 
When I put this # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

I get the error: SyntaxError: non ASCI character '\xff' in file