# Non latin symbols in django-simple-rest

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8, python-2.7

Making simple REST service (on django-simple-rest), in first iteration planning only GET. Everything good, but in response i receiving cyrillic symbols as:

```
>\u041c\u043e\u043b\u043e\u043a\u043e
```

in my experiments, i finded a line:

```
recipes_rest = json_serializer.serialize(Post.objects.all())
return HttpResponse(recipes_rest, content_type='application/json; charset=utf8', status=200)
```

if i use:

```
recipes_rest = 'some non latin symbols'
```

all is fine. But in my case http://cooktalks.ru/contacts i can't find a resolution. Maybe i have to do something in this line(?):

```
recipes_rest = json_serializer.serialize(Post.objects.all())
```

**UPDATE**
If i using 'xml', all is fine: 
`contacts = serializers.serialize("xml", Post.objects.all())`

Comment: If i using 'xml', all is fine: 
`contacts = serializers.serialize("xml", Post.objects.all())`

Answer (score 1):

From this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198765/how-to-write-russian-characters-in-file), did you try to import [codecs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html)?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved))**

Read this beautiful documentation:

If you’re using UTF-8 (or any other non-ASCII encoding) data with the JSON serializer, you must pass ensure_ascii=False as a parameter to the serialize() call. Otherwise, the output won’t be encoded correctly.

```
json_serializer.serialize(queryset, ensure_ascii=False, stream=response)
```