# How add russian language in LIKE

Tags: python, django

Got code

```
    if request.POST.get('search'):
        search = request.POST.get('search')
```

i have in search `пицца` -Russian literals

next i try do query with LIKE

```
    if search:
    shops = shops.filter(
        name__icontains=search)

Internal Server Error: /sort_rest_filter/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
response = get_response(request)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "E:\PhytonProgects\natarelke\catalog\views.py", line 28, in filter_ajax_check
response_data = ffunc.get_filer_data(request, response_data)
File "E:\PhytonProgects\natarelke\catalog\filer_functions.py", line 112, in get_filer_data
print(shops.query)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 811-813: ordinal not in range(128)
```

i think my problem in UTF-8 -  asc encoding
How i can fix it?

Comment: Did you encode your file?

Comment: As you're not using Python3, maybe from __future__ import unicode_literals might help you.

Comment: use 2.7... file have utf-8 encoding

Comment: If you're going to be doing anything involving unicode characters, you really should just use python 3

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `# -*- coding: encoding_code -*-` to the top of your file.

For example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP
...
```

I had this problem with Danish characters once. It solved my problem.

Comment: He was there before I just did not write about it

Comment: search come from AJAX request

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198765/how-to-write-russian-characters-in-file