# Decoding strings from textfile

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding

I have a text file that is reading in another application's script. 
This how it looks like in notepad:

```
Одинцовская РЭС: М.О., Одинцовский район
Климовская РЭС: М.О., г.о. Подольск
Кульшовская РЭС: М.О., г.о. Подольск
```

This file is needed for two things:
1. Creating a dict of values, separated by ':'. I use this dict in another part of script
2. Allows user to select desirable value

[image]

Here is what user see when he launhes script.
When a certain value is selected I have to use it in dictionary. But the problem is that selection is in `unicode` format (because of features of script building in ArcGIS) while the dictionary's keys are `str`.
So I need a value in dictionary which looks like
`'\xce\xe4\xe8\xed\xf6\xee\xe2\xf1\xea\xe0\xff \xd0\xdd\xd1'` to be converted in unicode. But when I make `.encode('utf-8')` it throws an error

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
>>> c = b'\xce\xe4\xe8\xed\xf6\xee\xe2\xf1\xea\xe0\xff \xd0\xdd\xd1'
>>> c
b'\xce\xe4\xe8\xed\xf6\xee\xe2\xf1\xea\xe0\xff \xd0\xdd\xd1'
>>> c.decode('unicode_escape')
'Îäèíöîâñêàÿ ÐÝÑ'
```

The b'' prefix denotes sequence of 8-bit bytes.

Take a look at SO [read russian characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198765/how-to-write-russian-characters-in-file)

Comment: fine, that works! But is there a method for that, i.e. `new_word = b(c)`?