# Having Problems reading .xlsx and .csv files in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, csv, xlsx

I opened and manipulated a .csv file. It contains Cyrillic script. When I try to open and to save it as a .xlsx file i get an error.
When I save the new .csv file and open it, the Cyrillic script turns into random characters and is practically *unreadable* (РђРЅРіРµР», Р”РёРјРёС‚СЉСЂ, РњР°СЂРёСЏ etc.)
[You can see what i get as a result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUYEz.png)

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write Russian characters in file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198765/how-to-write-russian-characters-in-file)

Comment: This very much looks like an encoding problem. I can't give you a straight answer, but I certainly would look in the documentation for how to handle and preserve UTF-8 encoding. By the way, it certainly helps if you post your code. Other people can then try to reproduce your (erroneous) result.

Comment: Use `encoding='utf-8-sig'` for the CSV at least if you are viewing the file in Excel.  Show your code!

Answer (score 0):

Both output files opened in Excel correctly with this.  Note that `.to_excel()` requires an additional Python package to write Excel files.  I used `pip install openpyxl`:

input.csv:

```
Колонка1,Колонка2,Колонка3
Раз,два,три
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('input.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig') # or whatever the actual encoding
data.to_csv('output.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig')
data.to_excel('output.xlsx',encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

FYI, `.to_csv()` did *not* work with `utf8` alone, but `.to_excel()` did.

Comment: `TypeError: NDFrame.to_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'` and no such argument in documentation [DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel)